# Reordering and hiding pictures depending on filter and search bar

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to create a 'Pick your hero' thing. There are a total of 113 heroes, each are given tags respective to them, for example: wizard, fighter etc.

The way I've done it so far is create a container and add 114 total div's to that container. I have this:

```
.heroPics {
    background-image: url(newHeroes.jpg);
    background-size: 792px 792px;
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 11;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

for (var i = 1; i < 114; i++) { 
    srsHeroes[i] = document.createElement("div");
    srsHeroes[i].textContent = theNames[i];
    srsHeroes[i].className = "championPics " + theNames[i] + "-sprite";
    srsHeroes[i].draggable = false;
    srsHeroes[i].name = theNames[i];
    srsHeroes[i].num = i;
    heroSelection.appendChild(srsHeroes[i]);
}
```

I was thinking of creating an array, for example

```
wizard = [ 14, 17, 28, 34, 69, 90, 101 ];
```

and once they click on a checkbox to show only wizard heroes it would do a for loop to hide all 113 divs and then do:

```
  for (var i = 50; i < 70; i++) {   
    heroSelection.insertBefore(srsHeroes[wizard[i]], srsHeroes[115]);
//and also do style.visiblity = "visible";
    }
```

But it just seems like this is a bad approach to it, or really messy/ugly. I don't really like using library's, including jquery. Is using div's even the right approach? Can anyone with experience give me some advice or links to follow since I must be searching the wrong terms for this.

Also can someone give me some intro on how to create a search bar where they can write hero names and it does the same thing? Reordering and hiding everything properly. Could be cool to have a transition too but not necessary lol. Thanks in advance for reading and all your help.

EDIT: Added my own post since it would have made this too long, let me know what you think

Answer (score 0):

Using classes and jQuery, you can easily match all the divs with that class. If you give all your divs with wizard picts in them a class name of "wizard", then you can select all of them like this:

```
$("div[class='wizard']").show();
```

Then to hide the others, you could just do this:

```
$("div[class!='wizard']").hide();
```

Also, as you know you can use multiple classes, so you can have a div like this:

```
<div class="heroPics wizard">
```

This will first apply the heroPics class styles, then the wizard styles. the latter doesn't have to have anything in it, you can just use it to classify your divs.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 1; i < 114; i++) {
srsHeroes[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
}

var test = heroSelection.getElementsByClassName( 'fighter' );
var gg = 1;
var bg = 0;
for (var i = 0, j = test.length; i < j; i++ ) {
    test[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    test[i].style.transitionDuration= "1.5s";
    test[i].style.transitionTimingFunction="ease"
    test[i].style.left = -73 + (77 * gg) + "px";
    test[i].style.top = -10 + (90 * bg) + "px";
    gg ++;
        if(gg > 10) {
            gg = 1;
            bg ++;
        } 
}
```

This actually ended up working perfectly. Although I have to reset transitionDuration each time I believe since even to hide divs it would do a 1.5 sec delay if left like that. The insertNode actually fine too, but I couldn't find a way to animate it, here's the code for that if you are interested:

```
var test = heroSelection.getElementsByClassName( 'wizard' );
    for (var i = 0, j = test.length; i < j; i++) {
        test[i].style.visibility = "visible";   
    heroSelection.insertBefore(test[i], heroSelection.firstChild);
```

the firstChild syntax is awesome, but no animation I ended up switching everything to absolute position, adding a transition duration and just setting the left and top every time.